# Install apk with multiple signature?

Tags: android, certificate, apk, signature

Is it possible to sign an apk multiple times, so It has multiple signature at the same time, does Android support installing these apk?

And If yes, Can I install an app with two cert (x & y) over the same app with only one cert (x)?

Comment: you can install only 1 apk per package ID. So you can't install 2 APKs with 1 package and different signatures. Also you can't install an apk with another signing on top of another APK. You will have to uninstall first one before

Comment: Not different signature! I edited the question.